# Проблема при отправке данных с формы в БД wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Добрый день, граждане. Не от большого ума вам пишу. Это все очень ново для меня, и я пытаюсь самостоятельно слепить подобие лэндинга. И возник вопрос отправки данных с формы сайта в БД wordpress. 
Для начала покажу код **формы**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.progressivetrade.org/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/events/csv.php">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_sname" placeholder="Имя и Фамилия">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_email" placeholder="E-mail">              
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <button id="btn_info" class="forex_button"> Я участвую</button>
</form>
```

и сам файл **csv.php**

```
<?php<br>
CONST HOST = 'localhost'; <br>
CONST USER = 'u0258277_default';<br>
CONST PSWD = 'PyE26in8';<br>
CONST DB = 'u0258277_kaloos';<br>

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PSWD, DB);<br>
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8"); <br>
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");<br>
$name = $_POST['add_sname'];<br>
$email = $_POST['add_email'];<br>
$phone = $_POST['add_phone'];<br>
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];<br>
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; <br>
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];<br>
$query = "INSERT INTO leads (`fsname`,`email`,`phone`,`datetime`, `user-agent`, `ip`,`url`) VALUES($name,$email, $phone , $datetime, $user_agent, $ip, $url)";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);<br>

echo $query;<br>
print_r($_POST);<br>
?>
```

И немного скрипта в хэдере:

```
<script>
    var MyAjax = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/progressivetrade.org\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
            jQuery.get(MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
                                 name:name,
                email:email,
                tel:tel,
                               },function(data){
                                });

//для неавторизованных пользователей
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_test', 'my_ajax_guest_lure');
//для авторизованных пользователей
add_action( 'wp_ajax_test', 'my_ajax_guest_lure');

</script>
```

И при вводе данных форму получается вот такая вот штука:

```
INSERT INTO leads (`fsname`,`email`,`phone`,`datetime`, `user-agent`, `ip`,`url`) VALUES(Валерка Пупкин,email@email.ru, 0961245657 , 2016-12-02 16:22:56, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36, 176.241.107.18, http://progressivetrade.org/events/)Array ( [add_phone] => 0961245657 [add_sname] => Валерка Пупкин [add_email] => email@email.ru )
```

ВРоде как и данные собирает, но БД не обновляется. Подскажите где я стратил?
Спасибо, что дочитали)))

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете WP нет ничего легче чем писать в бд,

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_sname" placeholder="Имя и Фамилия">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <input class="inp1" type="text" name="add_email" placeholder="E-mail">              
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <button id="btn_info" name="contact-form" class="forex_button"> Я участвую</button>
</form>
```

код поместить в fuinctions.php

```
function theme_form_init() {

    if( ! isset($_POST['contact-form']) ) return false;

    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
        'fsname'     => isset($_POST['add_sname']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['add_sname']) ) : '',
        'email'      => isset($_POST['add_phone']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['add_phone']) ) : '',
        'phone'      => isset($_POST['add_email']) ? esc_attr( trim($_POST['add_email']) ) : '',
        'datetime'   => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
        'user-agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 
        'ip'         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'url'        => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
    );

    $result = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'leads', $args );

    var_dump($result);
}
add_action('wp', 'theme_form_init');
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Удалил action из кода формы, и добавил присланный код в function.php, при вводе данных в форму и клику по кнопке не выбивается ошибка, но и не происходит запись в БД. Как было 0 строк, так и осталось.  что значит  isset($_POST['contact-form'])? у меня нет элемента с именем contact-form

Comment: Это я имя кнопки написал такое, можете у себя поставить. Оно будет сигнализировать хуку что выполняется запрос с контактной формы. Всё что я написал работает на php. Если нужен ajax то там немного по другому надо отлавливать

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю точно в чем причина, но возможно в экранизации, попробуйте вместо строки:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO leads (`fsname`,`email`,`phone`,`datetime`, `user-agent`, `ip`,`url`) VALUES($name,$email, $phone , $datetime, $user_agent, $ip, $url)";
```

Написать следующее:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO leads (`fsname`,`email`,`phone`,`datetime`, `user-agent`, `ip`,`url`) VALUES("'.$name.'","'.$email.'", "'.$phone.'", "'.$datetime.'", "'.$user_agent.'", "'.$ip.'", "'.$url.'")';
```

Comment: Попробовал, и выдает теперь : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/u0258277/data/www/progressivetrade.org/wp-content/themes/zerif-pro/events/csv.php on line 17. 17 строка это : $result = $mysqli->query($query);. И если я правильно понимаю не нравится форма записи?